# i cannot set the type of state in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, state

I'm writing code for server error handling using typescript in react(version 6).
But i got the error from useLocation and state.
useLocation got error which message is "Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.ts(2558)" So if i erase  then the error disappeared but still state have errors like "Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571) "

[image]

```
import { Button, Container, Divider, Paper, Typography } from "@mui/material"; 

import { useHistory, useLocation } from "react-router";

export default function ServerError() {
    const history = useHistory();
    const { state } = useLocation<any>();

    return (
        <Container component={Paper}>
            {state?.error ? (
                <>
                    <Typography variant='h3' color='error' gutterBottom>{state.error.title}</Typography>
                    <Divider />
                    <Typography>{state.error.detail || 'Internal server error'}</Typography>
                </>
            ) : (
                <Typography variant='h5' gutterBottom>Server Error</Typography>
            )}
            <Button onClick={() => history.push('/catalog')}>Go back to the store</Button>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the type of `state` is `unknown` in the `useLocation` type definition: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-location

Thus, you can use a cast to cast the `state` type as `any` to avoid those errors:

```js
const location = useLocation();
const state = location.state as any;
```

Or, if you know the type of `location.state`, you can cast it to a custom object type:

```js
const location = useLocation();
const state = location.state as { error?: { title: string; detail?: string } }
```

Comment: I use a cast to it and it works! Thank you so much!   const location = useLocation(); const state = location.state as any;